Components not loading in pages folder
So, I'm creating a webpage and I'm really new in creating pages on Next.js and also I'm using ShadCN for components.
Also, I'm adding Auth0 support for protecting pages and creating a log in.
The problem is that I created a pages folder to save my Auth0 config for login stuff and for future pages I'm going to protect.
The login works perfectly and loading the page inside of membersonly works, but the components doesn't load.
Tried :

adding the same component folder inside of the pages folder and it didn't work at all.
The other thing I tried was creating the page as a component and import it inside the index.tsx but not success at all.

Project/Folder Structure:

membersonly index.tsx :
"use client"

import { useState } from "react"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"

export default function ValorantCoachDashboard() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("dashboard")

  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen bg-gray-100">
      {/* Sidebar */}
      <div className="w-64 bg-white shadow-md">
        <div className="p-4">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-primary">Valorant Coach</h2>
        </div>
        <nav className="mt-4">
          {/* Botones de navegación */}
          <Button
            variant={activeTab === "dashboard" ? "secondary" : "ghost"}
            className="w-full justify-start"
            onClick={() => setActiveTab("dashboard")}
          >
            Dashboard
          </Button>
         
        </nav>
      </div>

      
      <div className="flex-1 p-8 overflow-auto">
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Dashboard</h1>
        {/* Contenido del dashboard */}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}




As you said : The login works perfectly and loading the page inside of membersonly works, but the components doesn't load. What is the page URL on which you are  able to see the page?

The first page loads fine an the app folder, but when adding the pages folder with the Auth0 config, the page loads but without components even when adding the components directly on the pages folder.


What is the page URL on which you are able to see the page? 2. Also add the minimal code for page in which you are using withPageAuthRequired. 3. Add details regarding any error messages.


I found out what was the error. So first of all, the /page folder doesn't need to be created (that was my bad) and all the pages need to be created in separated folders inside of /app. So for example, if you want to create a dashboard, you should create a folder called dashboard/page.tsx and inside here all the components will load correctly. Now the api folder will be moved inside of app for making sure that you import your getSession from the Auth0 Next.js library
const session = await getSession();
const user = session?.user;

After this, add the logic for making sure that the session is used and all should be working fine and the page will be protected. At least it worked in my case.

Problem :

I already tried by adding the same component folder inside of the pages folder and it didn't work at all. The other thing I tried was creating the page as a component and import it inside the index.tsx but not success at all.

Possible Cause :

Improper Folder Structure [1] [2] & file conventions [3], you are using app router (app folder present in your project structure). It has different folder structure & file conventions [3], it doesn't use Pages folder to create page [4].

Solution :
Move membersonly folder inside app, & change name index.tsx to page.tsx, then in browser go on http://localhost:3000/membersonly this should show your membersonly page.
Ex. dashboard page :

(image source : [6])

page.js/tsx located at root of app is \ home page,

page.js/tsx located at inside of dashboard folder is \ dashboard page,

In app router you have to create page by creating a folder with name as page name, then inside it add page.js/tsx [4].


You have used index.tsx in app router, which is not valid according to File conventions [3] [4].
API folder :

api (a.k.a Route Handlers) folder should also come inside, app folder [7].
Make api according to file conventions.

Route Handlers/API [7] :

(image source : [7])
Components Folder :

It can be placed inside or outside of app folder no issues [8] [9].


Further :

If you are not clear with app router basics/fundamentals, then you may take a free tutorial to learn the foundations of Next.js provided by Next.js itself: https://nextjs.org/learn


Read More:

Routing Fundamentals : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

Roles of Folders and Files : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#roles-of-folders-and-files

File Conventions : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#file-conventions

Creating Routes : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes#creating-routes

Route Handlers : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

Store project files outside of app : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation#store-project-files-outside-of-app

Store project files in top-level folders inside of app : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation#store-project-files-in-top-level-folders-inside-of-app

Pages : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages



It works but the problem now is that the Auth0 protection doesn't apply when adding withPageAuthRequired

Update the question, by adding the minimal code for page in which you are using withPageAuthRequired. Also add details regarding any error messages, if any.
